# Azure Databricks keep long-running notebook alive when closing browser

Tags: machine-learning, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working with Azure Databricks jupyter notebooks and have time-consuming jobs (complex queries, model training, loops over many items, etc.).

Every time I close the browser (or step away for a long time) of some running notebook, even before the cluster time-out time, notebooks and cluster will become idle. When I open the notebook again, it appears as if it the notebook resumes, but it does not continue executing. I'd like to keep the notebook running in the background at night or when I close the browser.

After opening the notebook the next day, this is what the notebook will show, as if trying to resume. It will stuck here.

[image]

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you sure the code actually stops executing and it is not just the output that stops working?
Are you using all-purpose clusters? Why can you not use jobs which are both better suited for this and also significantly cheaper?

Comment: It stops executing for sure. At the end there is supposed to be writing out to file/table. Cluster is High-concurrency, Standard. Could you elaborate on "jobs which are both better suited for this and also significantly cheaper" ?

Comment: Additionally to the normal all-purpose clusters Databricks features "Jobs" which run notebooks on a fixed schedule with one-time use clusters that are destroyed after the job is completed. These jobs are specifically designed to run without the user present. They have better capabilites regarding logging, error notifications and retrying failed tasks. Also Databricks charges less money for job clusters per DBU (e.g. Azure Standard Tier instead of $0.40, a Job Compute DBU costs $0.15).

More Information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-engineering/jobs/jobs

Comment: This issue seems unresolved in Azure DBX. The idea of using Jobs is a workaround the issue. However, imagine you're crafting a model and you don't have a clean notebook that deserves a Job. You'd like to be able to close your browser and reconnect later to find your finalised execution. Furthermore, Jobs create parallel versions of a notebook rather than a single history lineage. AWS-DBX works as intended, you can reconnect to a notebook to see executions even running in DBX cluster. It seems that Azure doesn't create a notebook server per account. Instead, everything is on the Driver node.